# rails use counts in different views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-models, grails-controller

Hello i **guess** this is going to be pretty noob question.. But..

I have an scaffold called list, which has_many :wishes. And with that information in my model, I can in my list view use this code

> 

well now I have made an controller called statusboard..
And in that' I have 3 functions.. Or how to say it.. but it is Index, loggedin, loggedout.. And .. In loggedin and in the file #app/views/statusboard/loggedin.html.erb i want to display this..

> Howdy {Username}, you have made {count lists} lists, and {count wishes} wishes

here is that i figured i should write in my file..

> Howdy {Username}, you have made <%=h @user.list.count %> lists, and <%=h @user.wishes.count %> wishes

my list model is like this =

> class List < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> attr_accessible :user_id, :name, :description
>
> belongs_to :users
>
> has_many :wishes
>
> end

and my wish model is like this =

> class Wish < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> attr_accessible :list_id, :name, :price, :link, :rating, :comment
>
> belongs_to :list
>
> end

and last my user model is like this =

> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
>
> # :token_authenticatable, :lockable and :timeoutable
>
> devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,# :confirmable,
>
> :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
>
> # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
>
> attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
>
> has_many :lists
>
> end

i hope someone can help me :-)!
/ Oluf Nielsen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the has_many :through association for user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :lists
  has_many :wishes, :through => :lists
end
```

and then you can use

```
@user.wishes.count
```

Comment: I did make something like that :-)! So thank you so much :-)!

Answer (score 0):

Write this method in user model

```
#copy the below code in /app/models/user.rb file`
def wishes_count
  counter = 0
  self.lists.each do |list| # this is similar to @user.lists 
    counter += list.wishes.count #this is similar to @list.wishes
  end
  return counter
end
```

> Howdy {Username}, you have made <%=h @user.list.count %> lists, and <%=h @user.wishes_count %> wishes

you can't use @user.wishes.count  since user is not directly related to wishes, hope this solution works for you. If any questions please drop a comment.

Comment: Hey, i don't realy know what's you mean there

Comment: wishes_count is an instance method of user model, see you can't use <%=h @user.wishes.count %> because, user.wishes doesn't exist, you can add methods to your user model, so i added a method called wishes_count, which is calculating the number of wishes for a user.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! But i wanted it to be a bit simpler, and that what was Voyta did :-) So I'll go with that ;-)!

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit tangential, but it shouldn't be necessary to use the h html sanitizing helper method on:

```
<%=h @user.list.count %>
```

since count is a ruby generated method and not user created.